# PathParam for Jersey WebResource

Tags: rest, jersey, jersey-client

I'm working on a task to create a Jersey client. I'm using Jersey 1.18. The target URL looks like below.

```
https://api.test.com/test/{id}?param1=test1&param2=test2
```

I need to add a `PathParam` to my `WebResource` to call this URL. I see an option to add the `QueryParam` but not for `PathParam`. My code looks something like this.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.test.com/test/{id}")
  .queryParam("param1", "test1")
  .queryParam("param2", "test2");
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

You need the `path` method from `WebResource`...

```
final String myId = "1234";
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.test.com/test")
                                .path(myId)
                                .queryParam("param1", "test1")
                                .queryParam("param2", "test2");
```

Comment: @Jane was referring to a path parameter and not a query parameter